# Limit of the sequence $\frac{1}{n}\left[\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)+\log\left(\frac{n+2}{n}\right)+\dots+\log\left(\frac{n+n}{n}\right)\right]$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, riemann-integration

How can we evaluate the following limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left[\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)+\log\left(\frac{n+2}{n}\right)+\dots+\log\left(\frac{n+n}{n}\right)\right]
$$

Comment: Isn't $\ln 1+\ln 2 +\ln 3+\dots+\ln n$ converges to $n\ln n-n$, and it does not seem to difficult to evaluate from here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the first principle,
$$\begin{align} \\ & \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left[\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)+\log\left(\frac{n+2}{n}\right)+\dots+\log\left(\frac{n+n}{n}\right)\right]
 \\ & =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left[\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+\log\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)+\dots+\log\left(1+\frac{n}{n}\right)\right]
 \\ & =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\log\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)
 \\ & =\lim_{h\to 0} h \cdot \sum_{r=1}^{n}\log\left(1+rh\right)
 \\ & =\int_0^1 \log\left(1+x\right) dx
 \\ & =\frac{1}{\ln 10}\int_0^1 \ln\left(1+x\right) dx
 \\ & =\frac{1}{\ln 10}\left[x\ln\left(1+x\right)-x+\ln\left(1+x\right)\right]_0^1 
 \\ & =\frac{1}{\ln 10}\left[(x+1)\ln\left(1+x\right)-x\right]_0^1
 \\ & =\frac{2\ln\left(2\right)-1}{\ln 10} \end{align}$$

Comment: @rubik Thanks for your edit.. :-)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 7):

The idea is to remark that it's a Riemann sum :

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \ln( 1 + \frac{k}{n} ) $$

So

$$\lim \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \ln( 1 + \frac{k}{n} ) = \int_0^1 \ln(1+x) dx = \left[ (x+1)\ln(1+x) -x \right]_0^1 = 2\ln(2) - 1$$

Comment: @Tryss Instead of integrating, you have differentiated.... Thats why your answer doesn't match mine... :-)

Comment: I think you've made a mistake. Since $\int_0^1 \ln(1+x)dx=2\ln(2)-1$

Comment: Oups, I made a mistake in the last equality. And I interpreted your log as ln. But it seems it was a base 10 logarithm, so log(x) = ln(x)/ln(10)

Comment: @SchrodingersCat : wow, what a splendid error ! I guess I was *distracted*